# Datatables sorting based on radio button and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables. I am getting few values in JSON as columns in datatables. In two of those columns , one has only radio buttons and one has only checkboxes. I want to sort on the basis of checkboxes (like if the checkbox is checked it should appear first) and radio buttons. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

See [Live DOM ordering](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html) example.

```
/* Create an array with the values of all the checkboxes in a column */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
    return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
        return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
    } );
}

/* Initialise the table with the required column ordering data types */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columns": [
            { "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: What if I don't want to click on a column to change the sorting, and instead I want the table to be populated automatically based on a selected radio button where the row with selected radio button is the top one?

Comment: @gene, you can apply initial ordering to the column containing radio buttons using [`order`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order) option.